# Are these logical equivalences correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am currently trying to nail down tautologies. However I tried solving a question and got a bit confused its asking for solving by logical equivalences.

This are the questions:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\neg(\neg p\wedge p)\vee q \\
\underbrace{\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
p&q&(\neg p\wedge p)&\neg(\neg p\wedge p)&\neg(\neg p\wedge p)\vee q \\\hline
T&F&F&T&T \\
F&T&T&F&T \\
T&T&F&T&T \\
F&F&F&T&T \\
\end{array}}_{\text{Tautology}} \\
\\
(p\Rightarrow p)\wedge\neg(q\Leftrightarrow q) \\
\underbrace{\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
p&q&(p\Rightarrow p)&(q\Leftrightarrow q)&\neg(q\Leftrightarrow q)&(p\Rightarrow p)\wedge\neg(q\Leftrightarrow q) \\\hline
T&F&T&T&F&F \\
F&T&T&T&F&F \\
T&T&T&T&F&F \\
F&F&T&T&F&F \\
\end{array}}_{\text{Contradiction}}
\end{array}
$$

Thank you

Comment: Is there a typo in the third column first table? Not p and p?

Comment: I think you entered your elements incorrectly.  Consider $\neg (\neg p \wedge p)$.  What is its value?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not quite so.   The column for $\neg p\wedge p$ should be *false* in every row; making $\neg (\neg p\wedge p)$ *true* in every row .

Otherwise the truth tables are okay.

However, they are redundant except as a matter of exercise.   You don't need them to solve this.

---

Since $\neg p\wedge p$ is a contradiction, clearly ${\neg(\neg p\wedge p)\vee q}$ will be a tautology.

Since $q\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology, clearly ${(p\to p)\wedge\neg (q\leftrightarrow q)}$ must be a contradiction.

Think about the reason why that might be so.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the final column in both your examples. In the final column of the first one, all are true, so it's a tautology. In the final column of the second one, they're all false, so it's a contradiction.

I'll need more context to say anything about your statement about logical equivalences.